# Data tables effect not display

Tags: javascript, gridview, datatables

when i try below code then effect not display on gridview1 .. gridview1 display without any effects means simple gridview is display this is beacuse date links
when i remove these links then effect visible on gridview1 but when i add date links then effect not display on girview1

any solution?

**UPDATE:**

HEAD

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />

<link href="Styles/stylechart.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script type="text/javascript"  src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"   src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"   src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="//cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="//cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
    <link href="Styles/grid/buttons.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />   


<!--for date--%>-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript"  src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"   src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>





     <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#GridView1").prepend($("<thead></thead>").append($(this).find("tr:first"))).dataTable({
          "aoColumnDefs": [{ 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [3] }],
          "scrollY": 200,
          "scrollX": true,
          dom: 'Blfrtip',
          lengthMenu: [
              [10, 25, 50, -1],
              ['10 rows', '25 rows', '50 rows', 'Show all']
          ],
          buttons: [
              'excelHtml5'
          ]
      });
  });
```

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(function () {
             $("#fromdate").datepicker({
                 dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
             });
             $("#todate").datepicker({
                 dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
             });
         });

    </script>
     <style>

       div.dataTables_wrapper {
        width: 1200px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-left:20px;
    }

         </style>
</head>
```

body

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
  <span>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
        </span>

        <span>
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="From Date"></asp:Label>

    <input id="fromdate"   value="dd/mm/yyyy" runat="server" clientidmode="static" />
</span>

     <span>
     <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="To Date"></asp:Label>

     <input  id="todate"   value="dd/mm/yyyy" runat="server" clientidmode="static" />
 </span>

        <span>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        </span>
        </div><br />

        <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" class="display nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%" runat="server"></asp:GridView>

        </div>

    <div>      
            </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

update:

now effect is visible on gridview but export button are not display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change the selector, since usually dotnet change the object `ID` value which have `runat="server"` attribute.

---

For example, I've add new class named `GridView1`:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" class="GridView1 display nowrap" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
```

So, in JS you need to change the selector too:

```
$('.GridView1').DataTable({
  ...
});
```

---

**UPDATE 1 :**

Just little mistake, you've add `jqueryUI` before `jquery` file loaded. Check my snippet:

Refers to [datatables](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/simple.html) site, They've said:

> Please note that the copy, excel, csv and pdf button types may also
>   use the HTML5 button types noted here, **providing a Flash fallback for
>   older browsers (IE9-)**.

1. Have you check your environment?
2. Perhaps SO not allowing us to add some FLASH object into snippet

---

**UPDATE 2 :**
Cleaning-up your included JS files.

```js
$(function () {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
      'copyHtml5',
      'excelHtml5',
      'csvHtml5',
      'pdfHtml5'
    ]
  });
  
  $("#fromdate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
  });
  
  $("#todate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
  });
});
```

```css
div.dataTables_wrapper {
        width: 1200px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-left:20px;
    }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript"  src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
  
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />

<link href="Styles/stylechart.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    
<script type="text/javascript"   src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"   src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="//cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="//cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
    <link href="Styles/grid/buttons.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />   


<!--for date--%>-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
  <span>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
        </span>

        <span>
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="From Date"></asp:Label>

    <input id="fromdate"   value="dd/mm/yyyy" runat="server" clientidmode="static" />
</span>

     <span>
     <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="To Date"></asp:Label>

     <input  id="todate"   value="dd/mm/yyyy" runat="server" clientidmode="static" />
 </span>

        <span>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        </span>
        </div><br />

        <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" class="display nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%" runat="server"></asp:GridView>

        </div>

    <div>
        <table id="example" class="display nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: i just add your girdview html code.. but date time picker and formatting not display .. and error on console..  Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function when i add datetime picker links..

Comment: @user6628729: can you give me simple generated table output? since, you've only add little piece of your page. I can't see whats wrong with your DOM..

Comment: but where is export buttons ? @Fadhly Permata

Comment: @user6628729: what 'export button' you've not mention any export button anywhere

Comment: but i think these export to excel /pdf /csv are autogenertaed when we use datatable links

Comment: There are no **"EXPORT BUTTON!!!"**... Dude, i think this become rude, you've change your question each time i've answer your last question. Why don't you create a new question instead?

Comment: export button means copy,excel,csv,pdf buttons which is display in this link https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/simple.html

Comment: @user6628729: Check again my updated answer. Sorry, my bad, I've not seen your load so many JS files.. So I've cleanup now..And now, you can see the export button.